# Communicating with server over Websocket using SocketConnect

Tags: streams, webservices, networking, socket

I am trying to connect to a web socket feed of Gdax. The documentation is here, https://docs.gdax.com/#websocket-feed. There is no account needed and the information is public.  I have successfully connected see this post, [SocketConnect not connecting to web socket address](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165295/socketconnect-not-connecting-to-web-socket-address)

After connection, a subscription message needs to be sent. My json looks exactly like the documentation but not successful.

```
socket = SocketConnect["ws-feed.gdax.com:80"];

json = ExportString[<|"type" -> "subcribe", 
"product_ids" -> {"ETH-USD", "ETH-EUR"}, 
"channels" -> {"level2", 
  "heartbeat", <|"name" -> "ticker", 
   "product_ids" -> {"ETH-BTC", "ETH-USD"}|>}|>, "JSON"];

WriteString[socket, json]

result = ReadString[socket]
```

Yields an error message.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 18:14:59 GMT

Content-Type: text/html

Content-Length: 177

Connection: close

Server: cloudflare-nginx

CF-RAY: -



<html>

<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>

<body bgcolor=\"white\">

<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>

<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>

</body>

</html>
```

I also tried this as a `HTTPRequest` and returns same error message.  I have also tried the request as a PUT to no avail.

```
request = HTTPRequest[<|"Body" -> json, Method -> "GET"|>];

WriteString[socket, request]

result = ReadString[socket]
```

Comment: To establish a websocket connection, you must complement [the opening handshake](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-4) first. This is not the same thing with socket and not implemented as built-in function, so you'll have to write it yourself (generally by following the spec). FYI there are utilities like [websocketd](http://websocketd.com) exist. Combining with [process functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DirectControlOfExternalProcesses.html), they might be a big time saver.

Comment: @Silvia thank you for the help.  I would have just assumed, like every other web socket package out there, it handles the handshake in the background.  I will put in a feature request.

Comment: You're welcome! I think the socket ability in current version of Mathematica is intended for a more general, low level purpose. Websocket on the other hand is a higher level application. It would be very nice if you come back with further information from the feature request! :D

Comment: Did you find anything new? I also have some issues with `SocketConnect` (see [166571](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166571/socketreadmessage-never-stops)).

Comment: No.  I have emailed Wolfram and they "...forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided. "  So I wouldn't expect anything soon.

Comment: I think this comes down to (in the http case NOT the https case) sending a properly formatted plain text http request.  HTTPS requires a handshake that is a little more complicated.  I think if we can format the http request correctly, it would work.  It gets a little complicated when there is a body full of JSON, etc.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: No I gave up.   I think we need Wolfram to implement it.  If you get something to work, let me know!